# Java streams, create custom stateful operation

Tags: java, android, java-8, java-stream

I want to create my own stateful operation with streams, for example, I want to create a custom reduce operation, that combine some of the items and some not (according to my rules), for example: [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [1 + 2, 3 + 4].

It will be nice if I could implement my version of `java.util.stream.DistinctOps` but since I can't, I need another way to implement my operations.

Meanwhile, in order to implement this operation, I collected the stream, performed my operation and then returned a new stream:

```
public Stream<Integer> myOperation(Stream<Integer> stream) {
    List<Integer> list = stream.collect(toList());
    list = preform operation...
    return list.stream();
}
```

But I want to implement this operation without performing a terminal operation, Any ideas?.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a question here?  You've already demonstrated a plausible way to do what you want.  The only real alternative is to call e.g. `stream.iterator()`, write your own `Iterator` view, and turn that back into a stream.

Comment: I want to implement this operation without performing a terminal operation (like collect or iterator) @LouisWasserman

Comment: That's not possible.  Streams aren't really designed for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want to implement this operation without performing a terminal operation, Any ideas?.

There is really, truly, no way to do it without performing a terminal operation.  All intermediate, nonterminal operations on streams are "rigid" in the sense that they don't permit you to perform custom behavior like this.